# What is "the URL" that restricts the Host header?

Tags: http, url, host

The following quote from [*HTTP The Definite Guide*](https://books.google.com/books?id=3EybAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT435&dq=If%20the%20URL%20contains%20a%20hostname%2C%20the%20Host%20header%20should%20not%20contain&pg=PT435#v=onepage&q=If%20the%20URL%20contains%20a%20hostname,%20the%20Host%20header%20should%20not%20contain&f=false) assumes "the URL" comes from somewhere and uses it to restrict the Host header. Where does "the URL" come from? Is it from the first line of a HTTP request (e.g. after `GET`), or from the input to a web client (e.g. an argument to `curl`, or the input in the address bar of a web browser)? Thanks.

> The Host header specifies the Internet host and port number for the
>   resource being requested, as obtained from **the original URL**:
>
> ```
> Host = "Host" ":" host [ ":" port ]
> ```
>
> In particular:
>
> • If the Host header does not contain a port, the default port for the
>   scheme is assumed.
>
> • If **the URL** contains an IP address, the Host header should contain
>   the same address.
>
> • If **the URL** contains a hostname, the Host header must contain the
>   same name.
>
> • If **the URL** contains a hostname, the Host header should not contain
>   the IP address equivalent to the URL’s hostname, because this will
>   break virtually hosted servers, which layer multiple virtual sites
>   over a single IP address.
>
> • If **the URL** contains a hostname, the Host header should not contain
>   another alias for this hostname, because this also will break
>   virtually hosted servers.

Comment: All of the above. Each of those is a way of requesting a URL.

Comment: The quote assumes the URL comes from somewhere and uses it to restrict the Host header. So where  does the URL come from?

Comment: Crap, I accidentally deleted my comment. curl and the browser are just HTTP clients that wind up issuing the same raw `GET foo` request under the hood. `foo` is the original URL.

Comment: It's entirely irrelevant to HTTP where the URL comes from. It could be from some web page a user was visiting, or something a user typed in because they saw it on TV.

Comment: @MichaelHampton The quote doesn't mean what you said. The quote describes some restrictions on the Host header, based on some URL specified somewhere.

Comment: Then what exactly are you asking?

Comment: @Tim Is there some underlying problem you're working on? You've got a half dozen kinda weird questions in the last 48 hours, each nibbling around the edges of similar subject matter with somewhat vague/odd misconceptions or partial understandings of it. If you tell us the actual problem you're looking to solve perhaps we can be more helpful.

Comment: @ceejayoz I am trying to understand the basics of HTTP and web servers, when learning about web services. Basics are not weird. My questions are different from each other, if you have some patience to read and try to understand.

Comment: @MichaelHampton How to understand the restrictions on the Host header, described in the quote.

Comment: @Tim If you want to access `http://127.0.0.1/`, you'd have `GET /; Host: 127.0.0.1`. If you want to access `http://127.0.0.1:1234/`, you'd have `GET /; Host: 127.0.0.1:1234`. Accessing `http://google.com/foo` means `GET /foo; Host: google.com`. It's just the rules of what parts of the URL being requested by the HTTP client (whatever that may be) need to be included in the Host header.

Comment: Based on your academic background, you might benefit more from reading the RFCs which are normative for the protocol you are asking about. For instance, see [RFC 7230](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230) sections 2.7 and 3, and the normative references linked therein.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks. I don't have academic background. I am just a self learner.

Answer (score 1):

The host field was introduced in the HTTPv1.0 standard and was optional.

In HTTPv1.1 you must use the Host field.

Before that standard, in HTTPv0.9 in example, the browser used to simply issue a single remote command, like;

```
GET example.com/index.html[cr][lf][cr][lf]
```

The [cr][lf] is carriage return, so a double carriage return on the line.

To better support SSL, and some other reason, in HTTPv1 they added the Host field.

In HTTPv1+ the same request in the browser would look like;

```
GET example.com/index.html[cr][lf]
Host: example.com[cr][lf]
[cr][lf][cr][lf]
```

or

```
GET index.html[cr][lf]
Host: example.com[cr][lf]
[cr][lf][cr][lf]
```

To request in example that;

```
GET example.com/index.html[cr][lf]
Host: contoso.com[cr][lf]
[cr][lf][cr][lf]
```

Would be a logic error, and it's against such thing the RFC warn you.

As you can see the URL is built by the remote server, depending how the query was wrote.